# Javascript: Mocking http call in Unit test case using sinon

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, sinon, chai

i have service resolvePromise method which returns promise.

```
resolvePromise() {
return this.$http.get('report-folder.json');
```

}

from my controller i call resolvePromise method of service

```
leftNavService.resolvePromise().then((response) => {
  this.itemList= _.map(response.data, 'folderName');
}).catch(function (e) {
  throw e;
});
```

I am using mocha-chai and sinon to write unit test cases. Below is my test case.
Am not able to execute the code from controller even-if i mock the service call. Basically i need to test the logic of controller in the promise. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 beforeEach(inject((_$rootScope_,  _$q_ , _$sessionStorage_) => {
$rootScope = _$rootScope_;
$q= _$q_;
$sessionStorage=_$sessionStorage_;
leftNavService = new LeftNavService('',$sessionStorage);
makeController = () => {
  return new leftnavController(leftNavService);
};
deferred = $q.defer();
promise = deferred.promise;
test=sinon.stub(leftNavService, 'resolvePromise').returns(promise);
deferred.resolve({jsonData});
```

}));

```
     it('should have assigned itemList', () => {

      sinon.assert.calledOnce(test);
      controller.initialize();
      console.log('Tester '+ controller.itemList);
assert.equal(controller.itemList, jsonData);
    });
```

there should be value of response in "itemList" of initialize method for that i am writing this test case. Basically i want test the logic in the promise.

Comment: $q promise chain requires $rootScope.$digest() / $rootScope.$apply() to be executed.

Comment: @estus i tried, but no luck :(

Comment: It should't be tried, it just should be there, the specs don't have a chance to work without it. There's currently no $rootScope.$digest() in your code. Please, show where you put it. Please, show where you call `makeController` and how `controller` is assigned. The entire controller code is also necessary.